# Unable to see Intel Graphics and Media setting in control panel after upgrading to Windows 8.1 for Sony VAIO Pro 13

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

Windows 8.1 is bad, quite bad, it keeps crashing, at least once a day. But that's fine, but the real issue is that the brightness keeps changing, it's annoying. And before the upgrade, I fixed this by disabling "Display Power Saving Technology" feature in Intel Graphics and Media setting in the control panel. Now it's gone. At least I cannot find it. BTW, all my drivers are up to date and I installed all the updates of Windows 8.1.

Comment: This is handled by a driver.  Have you installed a Windows 8.1 Intel Graphics driver.  A Windows 8.0 driver is not good enough.  Your crashing problems is isolated to your system because of driver problems.

Comment: I'd Agree with Ramhound this time around, sounds like a driver problem.

Comment: Yes, all my drivers are up to date according to Sony Vaio Update, including the intel graphics driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question then, to see the Intel Graphics settings, there is a igfxcpl.cpl inside C:\Windows\System32, click to run and you can change Intel Graphics settings